# aptana - Is there a way to have a command line inside aptana in pyDev?

Tags: aptana

when I am in web perspective - I have the a shell view open.
Now, I mainly use pyDev and I want a windows cmd line inside it. 
Does it have this feature (or an external plaugin)?

Answer (score 1):

If you're inside Aptana Studio 3, have you already checked the terminal view?

Another choice could be having IPython installed and use the PyDev interactive console (because IPython should be able to deal with windows commands... see: http://pydev.org/manual_adv_interactive_console.html and http://ipython.org/)